# Load data from text into different Strings

Tags: java

I have a textfile with data separated using tabulator. My goal is to load each of the data into a different Strings. My textfile looks like this: abc abcde abcdef and I have 3 Strings: x, y, z. My goal is to load abc into x, abcde into y and abcdef into z using scanner. However, my code is loading all of the 3 into single String, x. How do I achieve my goal? Thanks

My code looks like this:

```
public void Stringu(String file) {
    Scanner sc = null;
    String x;
    String y;
    String z;
    try {
        sc = new Scanner(new File(file));;
        sc.useDelimiter("/t");
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
                x = sc.next();
                y = sc.next();
                z = sc.next();

        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("file not found");
    } finally {
        if (sc != null) {
            sc.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution here is very simple. You have two options.

1. Use `sc.useDelimiter("\t");` with a backslash instead of `/t`. Backslash means special character (which in this case is a tab).
2. Option two, remove the line `sc.useDelimiter("\t");` all together. You can do that because `sc.next()` already separates content by whitespace by default.

Answer (score 0):

Change the logic inside while loop to this,

```
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            String[] split = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
            x = split[0];
            y = split[1];
            z = split[2];
        }
```

`nextLine()` will read the line with spaces so you won't have to use the `sc.useDelimiter("/t");`